# Is there a standard way to describe the data in JSON format, similar to a WSDL file for SOAP?

Tags: ruby, json

Basically, I want to be able to say that few fields have extra restrictions beyond "string" and "integer".  For example, field "user name" is 32 characters or less, "age" must be an integer greater than 21, etc.

Is there some standard way to specify this without the huge overhead of a WSDL file, preferably supported by a ruby gem of some sort?

Comment: You might want to describe your use case a little more in depth. The best thing to use may vary wildly depending on whether this data is for transport between servers, for internal models or for server-client communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the jsonschema gem
https://github.com/Constellation/ruby-jsonchema

more info http://json-schema.org/